# Xcode - Force Launch Screen to load in Landscape

Tags: ios, xcode

The launch screen is currently defaulting to the devices current orientation.
I have tried to set it programatically but it still doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait || UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown || UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown {
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The orientation of the device is never noticed by `viewDidLoad()`, because the code in `viewDidLoad()` runs before the view is rendered.  The code you wrote (or something like it) may work in `viewWillAppear()`.  I realize this question is very old, but I thought my comment might be useful to someone other than the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Device Orientation` in general setting of the target.

[image]

Ref: http://www.raywenderlich.com/63229/make-game-like-mega-jump-spritekit-part-12

Comment: I have to have all orientations on because of the app I'm making. I only want the splash screen to be landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with a solution. Launch screen is generated before the app runs, so here is a trick.

In your Project's General settings, only check Landscape Left&Right, so it will only generate landscape splash images. And swizzle the NSBundle's infoDictionary method as follows:

```
@interface NSBundle (Hook)
@end

@implementation NSBundle (Hook)

+ (void)load {
    [NSBundle jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(infoDictionary)
                    withMethod:@selector(hook_infoDictionary)
                         error:NULL];
}

- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)hook_infoDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary <NSString *, id> *dict = [[self hook_infoDictionary] mutableCopy];
    dict[@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"] = @[@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
                                                  @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
                                                  @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight",
                                                  @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown",
                                                  ];
    return [dict copy];
}

@end
```

Comment: looks great, is there a swift example?